# Visual Studio Multi-Device Hybrid App project + Ionic + WP8 White screen

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, ionic-framework, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I've created a Visual Studio Apache Cordova Multi-Device Hybrid App project with Ionic.
When I launch the app in windows phone 8, it loads a blank white screen right after the splash screen and nothing happens.
How can I fix this issue?
The app works fine on iOS and Android.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is because of cordova bug [AngluarJS router does not work on WP8 app](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7843) which was fixed in Cordova 3.7.0. You can try following to fix the issue:

1.) Uninstall Visual Studio Apache Cordova Multi-Device Hybrid App CPT2.0 and install Visual Update 4 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44921) and install CPT 3.0 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42675). More detail on Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova can be found [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/cordova-vs). Please note you need to first uninstall CPT2.0 before installing CPT3.0

refer this for uninstall issue http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3014133